# how to parse variable from loop into subprocess.pope

Tags: python

i am trying to write a python loop where i parse each variable name into a subprocess and run a bash script on the variable, but it keeps failing.

```
for i in range(0,len(DirectoryList)):
        try:
                startDir = "/dir/" + DirectoryList[i] 
                if os.path.exists(startDir):
                         os.chdir(startDir)
                         print("Analyzing x on" + " " + DirectoryList[i])
                else:
                        pass
        except:
                pass

for file in list(glob.glob("x.*")):
        try:
                ctimestamp = os.path.getmtime(file)
                if (time.time() - ctimestamp) > 300:
                        print(file)
                        JmCreate = subprocess.Popen(['jm -s', file])
                        print(pmxCreate.stderr)
                else:
                        pass
        except:
                pass
```

i am trying to parse 'file' to the bash script jm with the bash argument -s, and then print the output.
one increment would look like this: jms -s x.88821.
i am quite new to python.

Comment: You probably want `['jm', '-s', file]` instead of `['jm -s', file]`

Comment: i simply love you, i have been struggling with this for hours....